Filtering out rows where a date field equals another date field but could be a different record but with the same ID field
I am trying to filter out records where if ENROLLSTATSTDT EVER equals SEPARATIONDT, it is filtered out of the results. See below for an example - CIFID = 2920524969 has ENROLLSTATSTDT of 5/5/2018 (row 4) and SEPARATIONDT of 5/5/2018 (row 6) - therefore, it should be excluded from the results. Thank you!
See screenshot here
See above for the details.
